# Object composition in Web API using MEF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mef

I have an employee object:

```
public class CreateEmployee 
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Import]
    public ExtendEmployee ExtendEmployee { get; set; }
}

public class ExtendEmployee
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I want to extend this ExtendEmployee during runtime using MEF.

```
[Export]
public class ExtendCreateEmployee : ExtendEmployee
{
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }
}
```

I want to replace the ExtendEmployee with ExtendCreateEmployee in my Web API. Hence using MEF composition as shown below:

```
private void Compose()
{
    DirectoryCatalog catalog = new DirectoryCatalog(System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bin"), "*.dll");
    CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
}
```

I am calling the Compose() in the constructor of the API.

And my POST is like below:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CreateEmployee employee)
{
    return Created(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { controller = "CreateEmployee" }), "success");
}
```

I am passing the json as to the POST method:

```
{
  "firstName": "sample string 1",
  "lastName": "sample string 2",
  "extendAgentCommand": {
    "id": "sample string 1",
    "salary": 123098
  }
}
```

**

> ISSUE: The "ExtendEmployee" is not getting replaced with
>   "ExtendCreateEmployee" and its not able to receive the 'Salary' data
>   from the json. In other words, MEF is not composing/replacing the
>   object with Imported object. Please help if I am doing something wrong
>   and how can I achieve that.

**Is there any way in which I can replace this ExtendEmployee with ExtendCreateEmployee during runtime.**

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

You are expecting to get a `CreateEmployee` as your postdata:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] CreateEmployee employee)
```

While `CreateEmployee` has a `ExtendEmployee` property and not a `ExtendCreateEmployee` property.

Now I understand what you tried to do here, but you have to understand that you can't ask for one type and pass another type even though it's possible to do something like that in runtime (polymorphism).

In your case, the `web api` binder will not know what to do with the salary property and simply "drop" it.

`MEF` is a framework that knows how to compose types.

 `MEF` will not change you types, it will simply reflect your classes and match between the imports and the exports.

`MEF` has **nothing** to do with a post from your client.

Comment: Thanks. But is there any way in which I can replace this ExtendEmployee with ExtendCreateEmployee during runtime.

Comment: Yes. You can create a custom binder -> http://blog.learningtree.com/creating-a-custom-web-api-model-binder/ 
or
http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch13.html#_model_binders

Another way is to use a JObject (json.net) and handle the specific object conversion by yourself (using the ToObject method).

Comment: Thanks, Tried with the JObject and ToObject. Its still not taking the 'salary' field into consideration while mapping.

Comment: @Satyajit - That's because the inner object you have is the "problematic". You will need to use the ToObject method on the inner object if you choose to use JObject. This is not an elegant approach if you ask me, but it will work. If you choose the "JObject way" then read a bit more about how to use a JObject.

Comment: Thats the point and I want to avoid. I want to dynamically get the data in the replaced object instead of the old object. I dont know which object will be used during runtime.

Comment: You do know the type of the object and that's why you can use the ToObject approach (on the inner relevant object) or simply create a custom binder for that approach. It's your choice. I think you maybe should think about a better approach in you current design but you can make this work with either using a JObject or using a custom binder.

Comment: I mean to say here that the binding object is determined at runtime.